Как избежать тавтологии во фразах 'получатель получит' и 'отправитель отправит'?
Как избежать тавтологии во фразах 'получатель получит' и 'отправитель отправит'?

Адресант отправит, а адресат получит.  Отправитель пошлет (вышлет, отошлет), а получатель примет.
